# Content Security Policy invalid characters in 'self' in scorm environment

Tags: security, scorm, scorm1.2

I am publishing a course that has been tested in ScormCloud and runs without errors, but encounters errors and won't launch in various lms environments and the first error that occurs that stops the show is: The Content-Security-Policy directive name ''self'' contains one or more invalid characters. Only ASCII alphanumeric characters or dashes '-' are allowed in directive names. My first thought was this was an issue with the policy from the lms site, but since it is occurring on more than one lms, I am wondering if it is my course. And if so, does anyone have any idea how the course could be causing this error?

I am in the process of trying to connect the lms providers to see if they can shed some light on this. Meanwhile, I wondered if anyone has encountered this and if there are any ideas.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the structure of the course. Was this created using a 3rd party tool such as Articulate Rise? Did you build it yourself? For CSP 'self', check the pages for a meta declaration such as <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the security policy of the lms site that hosted my course did not allow references to the top of the window, i.e, top which I was using to reference back to an iframe in the course. Using parent.iframename solved the problem.